# How to remove the single quotation mark from every set of vector in the list variable?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, vector

I'm new to this website and I've just picked up Python to carry out my project.
I have come across this output when I was appending many sets of vectors into the variable "vectors" by appending it from a 'txt' file. The output shows that there are single quotation marks on every set of vectors from the 'txt' file after I had done appending it.

I want to remove every single quotation marks that can be seen in the variable list while maintaining the nature of the sets of vectors in the list. I have seen many good solutions from this website like using .join(), split(), map() and so on. I have tried it but it does not give me the solution that I want.

Here is the code for my programme

```
with open('output.txt', 'r') as result:
    df = pd.read_csv(result, header = None)
    grad = []
    vectors = []
    for row in range(len(df)):
        grad.append(df.iloc[row,0])
        for column in range(len(df.iloc[row,1:])):
            vectors.append(df.iloc[row,column+1])
```

The output for the variable "vectors" is as below:

```
In [30]:vectors
Out[30]: 
[' [-0.62338535 -0.62338535 -0.62338535 -0.62338535 -0.62338535]',
 ' [-0.6495707 -0.6495707 -0.6495707 -0.6495707 -0.6495707]',
 ' [-0.64999308 -0.64999308 -0.64999308 -0.64999308 -0.64999308]',
 ' [-0.64999989 -0.64999989 -0.64999989 -0.64999989 -0.64999989]',
 ' [-0.65 -0.65 -0.65 -0.65 -0.65]']
```

My ideal form for the variable should be like this:

```
[[-0.62338535 -0.62338535 -0.62338535 -0.62338535 -0.62338535],
 [-0.6495707 -0.6495707 -0.6495707 -0.6495707 -0.6495707],
 [-0.64999308 -0.64999308 -0.64999308 -0.64999308 -0.64999308],
 [-0.64999989 -0.64999989 -0.64999989 -0.64999989 -0.64999989],
 [-0.65 -0.65 -0.65 -0.65 -0.65]]
```

Here is the content from the "txt" file.

```
7.379024325749306, [-0.62338535 -0.62338535 -0.62338535 -0.62338535 -0.62338535]
0.1190243257493061, [-0.6495707 -0.6495707 -0.6495707 -0.6495707 -0.6495707]
0.0019198730746340876, [-0.64999308 -0.64999308 -0.64999308 -0.64999308 -0.64999308]
3.0967725290674006e-05, [-0.64999989 -0.64999989 -0.64999989 -0.64999989 -0.64999989]
4.995121929499646e-07, [-0.65 -0.65 -0.65 -0.65 -0.65]
```

Comment: It's very difficult to say without seeing the input

Comment: What does the data in your file look like?

Comment: The text file contains a value and a set of vectors in every row.

Comment: Your input file is text (as in, readable, not binary data). You are not converting from that text representation to the numerical data that you want.

Comment: @mpez0 how should I store it in binary data? I know the with() has the binary mode, just not sure how should I convert it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use NumPy instead of Pandas:

```
vectors = []
with open('output.txt') as result:
    for line in result.readlines():
        vectors.append(np.fromstring(line.strip()[1:-1], sep=' '))
vectors = np.vstack(vectors)
```

```
>>> vectors
array([[-0.62338535, -0.62338535, -0.62338535, -0.62338535, -0.62338535],
       [-0.6495707 , -0.6495707 , -0.6495707 , -0.6495707 , -0.6495707 ],
       [-0.64999308, -0.64999308, -0.64999308, -0.64999308, -0.64999308],
       [-0.64999989, -0.64999989, -0.64999989, -0.64999989, -0.64999989],
       [-0.65      , -0.65      , -0.65      , -0.65      , -0.65      ]])
```

Now you have a real NumPy array.

**Update**

> my "txt" file actually has another value before every vector set

```
vectors = []
values = []
with open('output.txt') as result:
    for line in result.readlines():
        value, vector = line.split(',', 1)
        values.append(float(value))
        vectors.append(np.fromstring(vector.strip()[1:-1], sep=' '))
values = np.array(values)
vectors = np.vstack(vectors)
```

```
>>> values
array([7.37902433e+00, 1.19024326e-01, 1.91987307e-03, 3.09677253e-05,
       4.99512193e-07])

>>> vectors
array([[-0.62338535, -0.62338535, -0.62338535, -0.62338535, -0.62338535],
       [-0.6495707 , -0.6495707 , -0.6495707 , -0.6495707 , -0.6495707 ],
       [-0.64999308, -0.64999308, -0.64999308, -0.64999308, -0.64999308],
       [-0.64999989, -0.64999989, -0.64999989, -0.64999989, -0.64999989],
       [-0.65      , -0.65      , -0.65      , -0.65      , -0.65      ]])
```

Comment: Very sorry that I did not mention in my question just, @Corralien, my "txt" file actually has another value before every vector set. Perhaps I should split both the value and vector apart first?

Comment: @KevinChoonLiangYew. I updated my answer to take into account your file format. Can you kindly check it, please?